# C++ use base class function to modify derived class

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Maybe the reason I can't find how to do this is because it isn't allowed. My brain is now confused and I can't solve this on my own. Here it is, simplified:
The problem is, change colours of dialogs in runtime.

```
#define NEW_COLOR         0x00C4FFFF
// the base class
class MyDialog : public CDialog
{
  //...
  COLORREF m_clrBkgnd;
  virtual void RefreshColor();
}
void MyDialog::RefreshColor()
{
    m_clrBkgnd = NEW_COLOR; 
    Invalidate();
    RedrawWindow();
}
// the derived class
class CTest : public MyDialog
{
// no m_clrBkgnd
// no RefreshColor
}

// in main
  CTest * m_pTestsDlg;
// here we decide to change the colours of all dialogs...
    if (m_pTestsDlg != NULL)
    {
        m_pTestsDlg->RefreshColor();
    }
```

It runs into RefreshColor nicely and changes the value of m_clrBkgnd, but the dialog does not change colour.

The point is, I have an awful lot of dialogs, and I want to do RefreshColor without changing the dialog code in any way. I have a feeling it must be possible to do this just by changing the base class. In my sample I just change the background colour, obviously there are buttons and stuff, but if I can get this to work I can extrapolate...
On the other hand it might just be plain impossible, and that's why I can't find the answer.
Some dialogs are very complicated and may have to have their own implementation after all.

**EDIT**

Here is where `m_clrBkgnd` is used:

```
HBRUSH MyDialog::OnCtlColor(CDC* pDC, CWnd* pWnd, UINT nCtlColor)
{    
  HBRUSH hbr = CDialog::OnCtlColor(pDC, pWnd, nCtlColor);
  switch (nCtlColor)
  {
    case CTLCOLOR_STATIC:
    {
      pDC->SetBkMode(OPAQUE); 
      pDC->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
      pDC->SetBkColor(m_clrBkgnd);// to set the background color 
      return (HBRUSH) hbr;
      break;
    }
    case CTLCOLOR_BTN:
    {
        pDC->SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT);
        return HBRUSH(m_brushHollow);
        break;
    }
    default:
      return (HBRUSH) hbr;
  }
}
```

Comment: The code you presented shows how you correctly change the `m_clrBkgnd` member. Do you expect those operations to change the actual background colour of your dialogs? Where is the code which uses `m_clrBkgnd`?

Comment: Are you sure you should use CTLCOLOR_STATIC? What about CTLCOLOR_DLG or CTLCOLOR_MSGBOX? What about creating and selecting the brush? Problems is not in virtual methods but seems to be in that OnCtlColor (updating m_clrBkgnd + Invalide() should be enough if OnCtlColor works)

Comment: It goes in CTLCOLOR_STATIC most of the time, because read-only CEdits go in there too, but this is just an example, there is normalls a CTLCOLOR_BTN in there too. I rather think m_clrBkgnd has gone out of scope, because even though OnCtlColor is called immediately afterwards it is the result of another message.

Comment: WM_CTLCOLOR does not work as intended to push buttons. You need to create an owner draw button if you want to change its color.

Comment: Every kind of component has a derived class, they work alright if I set them separately (RefreshColor for every dialog). I just thought I could use myDialog to set them all without changing the derived dialog code at all.

Comment: I found the answer. What I am doing is right, in theory, so that's the answer I wanted. But when I use RefreshColor to repaint my components, it then sends WM_CTLCOLOR, which calls OnCtlColor, which is overpainting the colour I just set. But that's another story and I shall now think about that one. Thankyou for the helpful replies, it made me think about what I'm trying to do.